# Загрузка UI из XML

Tags: linux, vala, gtk3

Пробую подгружать описание интерфейса из xml файла, что-то не выходит, что в данном случае не так и как будет правильно?

```
class MyApplication: Gtk.Application {
    private Gtk.Window window;

    protected override void activate() {
        window.show_all();
    }

    protected override void startup() {
        base.startup();

        var builder = new Gtk.Builder();
        try {
            builder.add_from_file("main.ui");
        } catch(Error e) {
            error("Unable to load file: %s", e.message);
        }

        this.window = builder.get_object("window") as Gtk.Window;
    }
}

public int main(string[] args) {
        return new MyApplication().run(args);
}
```

Ошибка при запуске:

> (main:25258): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_widget_show_all: assertion
>   'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed

main.ui — http://pastebin.com/XaVyDuaH

Comment: Покажите свой файл main.ui. Может проблема в нём.

Comment: Добавил ссылку.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в вашем ui. Вы пытаетесь загрузить из вашего файла с помощью Gtk.Builder виджет Gtk.Window c идентификатором window:

```
this.window = builder.get_object("window") as Gtk.Window;
```

Но вы не дали имя своему GtkWindow в Glade. Откройте свой main.ui и в свойствах в закладке **Основные** в поле **ID** дайте имя своему виджету.

Comment: Заработало, хотя есть ещё проблема, не подскадете почему после запуска сразу же закрывается приложение без ошибок?(появления окна даже не видно) Делал в ui только один label "Hello World", не помогло, идентичный пример только без билдера отсюда https://valadoc.org/gtk+-3.0/Gtk.Application.html работает нормально

Comment: Хотя нет, окно порой появляется но оно "мертвое", оно остаётся после закрытия приложения и всередине просто чёрное, к тому же не закрывается, ну а потом уже "не отвечает" и мне поступает предложение закрыть не отвечающее окно. Вот пример ui которое я сделал для теста http://pastebin.com/9Cjkautc в get_object правильный id окна указал

Comment: В вашем примере похоже не запускается основной цикл событий Gtk.main (). Добавьте это в функцию activate после window.show_all() и будет вам счастье. К сожалению не смогу ответить в чем подвох, почему в примере с Valadoc все работает, а в вашем случае нет.